# Client is not defined when trying to get Channels

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm trying to lock a channel between two times, but all I get is an error. I'm quite new to making discord bots, so this is my first one. Where are my errors, how can I fix them, and why does my code not work?

```js
Error:

    ReferenceError: client is not defined
    at getChannel (C:\Users\<User>\DISCORDBOT\main.js:42:2)
    at checkTime (C:\Users\<User>\DISCORDBOT\main.js:48:3)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\<user>\DISCORDBOT\main.js:53:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1138:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:986:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
```

Code:

```js
var Discord = require('discord.io');
var auth = require('./auth.json');
// Initialize Discord Bot
var bot = new Discord.Client({
  token: auth.token,
  autorun: true
});
bot.on('ready', function (evt) {
  bot.sendMessage({
    to: '<ID>',
    message: 'Bot Running!'
  });
})
bot.on('message', function (user, userID, channelID, message, evt) {
  // Our bot needs to know if it will execute a command
  // It will listen for messages that will start with `!`
  if (message.substring(0, 1) == '?') {
    var args = message.substring(1).split(' ');
    var cmd = args[0];

    args = args.splice(1);
    switch (cmd) {
      // !ping
      case 'ping':
        bot.sendMessage({
          to: channelID,
          message: 'Pong!'
        });
        break;
      case 'getinfo':
        bot.sendMessage({
          to: channelID,
          message: 'User Requested Channel data. User: ' + user + ', UserID: ' + userID + ', in ChannelID: ' + channelID
        });
        break;
      // Just add any case commands if you want to..
    }
  }
});

function getChannel(ID) {
  client.channels.get(ID)
}
function checkTime() {
  var today = new Date().getHours();
  console.log(today)
  if (today >= 7 && today <= 22) {
    getChannel("<ID>").updateOverwrite(getChannel("<ID>").guild.roles.everyone, { VIEW_CHANNEL: false });
  } else {

  }
}
checkTime()
```

**edit:**
I got a new error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
    at getChannel (C:\Users\<User>\DISCORDBOT\main.js:42:15)
    at checkTime (C:\Users\<user>\DISCORDBOT\main.js:48:3)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\<User>\DISCORDBOT\main.js:53:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1138:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:986:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
```

It seems like it can't get the channel... Anyone know a fix?
I don't know how much of the API, and I really don't understand at all. Sorry if you see very apparent errors that I overlook

Answer (score 0):

That is because you defined it as `bot` not `client`

```js
function getChannel(ID) {
    bot.channels.get(ID)
}
```